# Sending FCM messages from API server to multiple devices?

Tags: asp.net, firebase, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm currently working on enabling push-notifications in my application. My problem here is that I want to send all users, who are a member of a certain group, a notification, and I don't quite know the best practice for this use-case.

This is because there are both 'topics' and 'device-groups', but from what I could find, topics are more like subscribing to a news section of the app, and device-groups are mostly used for users with multiple devices connected to him/her.

What I want is to send a list of users a message, but I don't nessecarily want to make a topic for every group in the database, and I don't want to have to make a call to FCM for every member of the group. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gcm</groupId>
        <artifactId>gcm-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

add  dependency in pom.xml

```
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
        post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        post.setHeader("Authorization", "key="+<Your firebase application key>);

        JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
        List<FirebaseIOSToken> tokens; new Arraylist(); // get device tokens from database 

            if(tokens!=null) {

            for (FirebaseIOSToken token : tokens) {

            try {
                message.put("to",token.getDevicetoken());
            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            message.put("priority", "High");

            JSONObject notification = new JSONObject();
            notification.put("title", "Test Notification");             
            notification.put("body", "Hello World");
            notification.put("data", "Data");
            notification.put("id", "notification id");

            message.put("notification", notification);

            post.setEntity(new StringEntity(message.toString(), "UTF-8"));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            System.out.println(response);
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Token Not Fonund");
    }

    return "Sent";
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a good solution at [FCM docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json) where instead of using a "to" header parameter, I simply had to use the "registration_ids" parameter, in which I can parse multiple tokens as an array.